# MongoDB aggregation lookup array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have three documents called location, company and vouchers and they structured as follows,

```
    "company": [
        {
          "_id": "625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
          "name": "C1",
          "location": "L1",
          "category": "A"
        },
        {
          "_id": "625ba41651828244cefa138b",
          "name": "C2",
          "location": "L2",
          "category": "B"
        },
        {
          "_id": "625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
          "name": "C3",
          "location": "L3",
          "category": "B"
        }
    ]


    "vouchers":[
       {
          "_id":"625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
          "name":"V1",
          "color":"#ad7f7f",
          "category":[
            "A",
            "B"
          ]
       },
       {
         "_id":"625ba41651828244cefa138b",
         "name":"V2",
         "color":"#9A348E",
         "category":[
           "A"
         ]
       },
       {
         "_id":"625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
         "name":"V3",
         "color":"#31263E",
         "category":[
           "B"
         ]
       },
       {
         "_id":"625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
         "name":"V4",
         "color":"#31263E",
         "category":[
            "C"
         ]
       }
    ]
```

and the expected result should be

```
"companies":[
  {
     "_id":"625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
     "name":"C1",
     "location":"L1",
     "category":"A",
     "vouchers":[
        {
           "_id":"625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
           "name":"V1",
           "color":"#ad7f7f",
           "category":[
              "A",
              "B"
           ]
        },
        {
           "_id":"625ba41651828244cefa138b",
           "name":"V2",
           "color":"#9A348E",
           "category":[
              "A"
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "_id":"625ba41651828244cefa138b",
     "name":"C2",
     "location":"L2",
     "category":"B",
     "vouchers":[
        {
           "_id":"625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
           "name":"V1",
           "color":"#ad7f7f",
           "category":[
              "A",
              "B"
           ]
        },
        {
           "_id":"625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
           "name":"V3",
           "color":"#31263E",
           "category":[
              "B"
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "_id":"625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
     "name":"C3",
     "location":"L3",
     "category":"C",
     "vouchers":[
        {
           "_id":"625ba4d651828244cefa1951",
           "name":"V4",
           "color":"#31263E",
           "category":[
              "C"
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to get the expected result by using mongodb aggregation pipeline. First I filtered location documents with $geoWithin and used $lookup to find the related companies. Next I should get all the vouchers which having same category as company. I applied bellow code to previous result to get vouchers.

```
$lookup: {
        from: "vouchers",
        let: { category: "$company.category" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [{ $in: ["$category", "$$category"] }],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "vouchers",
      },
```

But it gives empty result after this stage. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these really three **documents** (Not rather *collections*)? I don't see any `location` document.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit  There are three collections called location, company and vouchers, After few pipeline stages it resulted list of companies, it looks like {
          "_id": "625ae79a51828244cef979d4",
          "name": "C1",
          "location": "L1",
          "category": "A"
        },   it contains the data from location collection as L1, for next step I need to list vouchers as a list

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-FOClAOYzCS)? It's basically fixing some minor "errors" like the `let` part and the incorrect ordering of `$in`

Comment: The question/docs/etc. are a bit ambiguous. Is `"$company.category"` going to be an array because it is from a previous `"$lookup"`?

Comment: @sAntd thanks for confirming first. But sorry to say that I am voting to close this question as the root cause is just incorrect usage of syntax.